# Debug Undefined index ban end php

Tags: debugging

I have 2 debug notices both this message below

[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file [ROOT]/memberlist.php on line 428: Undefined index: ban_end

the line in question is 
if ($member['ban_end'] >= time() || $member['ban_end'] == '0')

now if i add isset like this it kills 1 debug

if (isset($member['ban_end']) >= time() || $member['ban_end'] == '0')

how do i apply isset so both ban_end gets covered by isset

Answer (score 0):

The code you post won't work since it's comparing the value of `time()` against a boolean.

You could do this:

```
if (isset($member['ban_end'])) {
  if ($member['ban_end']) >= time() || $member['ban_end'] == '0') {
  // some code
  }
} else {
  // do something if variable not set
}
```

You probably need to understand why the variable isn't set though, rather than applying a band-aid fix.